# number in array's column title causing problems

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

This should be simple, but I never came across it and cannot find any information about it either.

I have a column title inside one of my db tables called '24h_format'.  After making a query I am having trouble actually referencing this column in my result array due to the name.  The error is unexpected '_format' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM program_settings WHERE computer_id = ".$value[computer_id]."");
$settings = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '...some stuff.... value="'.$settings[24h_format].'">....some stuff....';
```

Is there a way around this other than changing the column name in the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String keys in arrays should be enclosed in quotes:

```
echo $settings['24_format'];
```

As pointed out by  bagonyi. You are also using the wrong key:

```
echo $settings['24h_format'];
```

Comment: No, that does return any value whatsoever when in that format.

Comment: What result do you get from `var_dump($settings);`?

Comment: haha - must've deleted that when I added the 's and didn't realize it. Thanks. Time for a break.

Comment: It probably **is** returning a value (albeit an empty one), but now you're not getting the PHP error anymore so nothing shows up.